# Explorer view not working - SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, list, list-view

Navigate to a document library with 20 documents.

Click "Explorer View" on the document library web part and nothing happens. The screen goes blank as if it were trying to load but windows explorer never opens showing the document library.

[image]

However!

If I select a single or multiple files and then use the ribbon button "Open with Explorer" it works almost instantaneously.

[image]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

I'm quite sure that the option you see in your screen shot is actually a view that someone has created. I do not have that view in my environments, so I would guess it is a custom view (possibly with some custom code that intend to open Explorer View).

Since it is no out of the box functionality it is hard to help you any further without more details about that specific view. The default way to open a document library in Explorer is by using the ribbon button from your second screenshot.

Comment: That explains everything. This must of pulled over from the migration. Now I just need to find a way to remove that "explorer view" view from every document library. Thanks for your help Robert.